# Why multiple instances of a django app?

Tags: django

I have been reading a lot of django articles, including the official doc. Occasionally, I would see multiple instances of an app being mentioned without going into the details of it. This leads me to start thinking what are the uses/applications of having multiple instances of an app. A few examples would be appreciated.

In the section URL Dispatcher of the official doc, I read:

> The Django Admin is deployed as instances of a AdminSite

Why multiple instances are needed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example make another instance of `AdminSite` available under a different url than `/admin` - you could for example register different ModelAdmins with this second instance or have it customized in a different way. In the Django documentation you will also find [some attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes) of `AdminSite` that give you the possibility to customize it.
Also there can be use cases where you would need to subclass `AdminSite` to give it the properties you desire...

Comment: Thanks. How would I set up multiple instances of a single django app? Do I just use `include` with different instance namespace in the main URLconf?

Comment: @ahmoo its not namespace, all instances of an app share one; its current_app.

Comment: @okm - I don't quite get what you mean. Can you please elaborate on what you said? Thx

Comment: @ahmoo I meant that when you want multiple instances of a single app, it's better to use `current_app` to identify them instead of using different namespace. The two ways could achieve same thing, but taking up as least global namespace as possible is always nice. [The doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces)

Comment: @okm - I see what you mean now. Basically, you are suggesting me to use `current_app`, whenever possible, to distinguish an app instance from the others. Thanks for the tip. But, to make myself clear, my question was not concerning with how to access but how to **set up** multiple instances of a single app. My understanding, if not wrong, is that I would need to give separate instances with different instance namespaces in the main URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

Say you design an app that creates a forum with categories, sub-categories, user profiles etc.  Now company A that makes cars wants to use your software without going through the trouble of hosting it. So does company B that makes bikes. You could host both of them as multiple instances of your forum app.

Another example would be something like [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) that can be hosted on your domain. Each separate instance contains email, docs & a lot more. You can add whichever apps you want.